# Newsmap topic classification: issue with "predict" step of the newsmap process

Tags: r, topic-modeling, quanteda

I am giving a try to the Newsmap package for topic classification (not geographical, but you know, implementing to other tasks...). I follow the instructions from the Quanteda tutorials website ([here](https://tutorials.quanteda.io/machine-learning/newsmap/https://)).

Everything runs smoothly until I try to predict the topic most strongly associated with each of my texts.

Here is the code:

```
labels <- types(toks_labelExclu)

dfmt_label <- dfm(toks_labelExclu, tolower = FALSE) # The dfm with the labels of my 35 topics

dfmt_feat <- dfm(toks_sent) %>%
  dfm_trim(min_termfreq = 50) # The dfm with the features to be associated with my topics

model_nm <- textmodel_newsmap(dfmt_feat, dfmt_label)

coef(model_nm, n= 20)[labels] # All good so far

pred_nm <- predict(model_nm)
# Here is the snag: the function returns 

Error in x[, feature] : Subscript out of bounds
```

Does anyone have an idea of where the error could come from?

For information, here is the sessionInfo:

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.4

other attached packages:
[1] newsmap_0.7.1  quanteda_2.0.1
```

Comment: If you suspect it is a bug, please post that to https://github.com/koheiw/newsmap/issues with a replicable code.

Comment: You can avoid the error by removing padding when you construct the DFM `dfm(toks_sent, remove = "")`

Comment: @KoheiWatanabe, thanks! And thank you for your piece of advice on my dictionary!